# FFMpeg extract frames and save to memory

Tags: memory, ffmpeg, frames, movie

How can I extract frames from movie and save it to memory? I am using FFMpeg and I can extraxt frames to save in on disc but then I need to processing that files and load it to memory. Is there any way to save them directly into RAM ?

Comment: You could probably do this e.g. by having FFMpeg write on a RAM disk, but why do you need this? What is your platform and context?

Comment: The main goal of the project is to improve quality of the movie and I am writing wpf application which uses FFMpeg as child process with specified arguments for example to extract frames from the movie. After the extraction I need to load all images and improve for instance contrast, histogram and so on.. and it works but to slow... I think if there is any possibility to get frames iteratively and omitthe first saving on the disk and load it directly into ram

Comment: I very much doubt whether the act of writing the image on the disk is a factor in that process! But if you really think this is an option, you could try mounting a RAM disk (see http://serverfault.com/questions/128672/what-do-you-use-for-a-ram-disk-on-windows-server for Windows-based solutions) and have FFMpeg write the images to it.